# Is there any way to get online status from whatsapp into another android app

Tags: android, social-networking

Please explain if there is any way to get online status of a particular contact from my whatsapp into another android application.
Thanks

Comment: WhatsDog app is doing this same...how ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not unless WhatsApp is willing to expose its API which returns the online status of the requested contact.

Comment: WhatsDog app is doing this same...how ??

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have done it, I used Selinium webdriver, it opens the web.whatsapp page of the person which we are tracking `***driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=91xxxxxxxx&text&app_absent=0&lang=en")***`, and it could **scrape** the online status of that persons and we could loop this process over and over again and when ever the status changes from online to null or vice verse we could notify this to our app or telegram bot,

---

```
while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        a = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/header/div[2]/div[2]/span').text
        if c!=a and a!="click here for contact info":
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            print(a+' @ '+ now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
            c='online'
    except Exception:
        if c != 'offline':
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            print("offline"+' @ '+ now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
            c = 'offline'
```

---

but this process has a lot of limitations , not good for tracking multiple account at once.